# i'm stuck incrementing page variable in infinite scrolling with Ajax.BeginForm

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm implementing infinite scroll in MVC 5, by Ajax.BeginForm invoking an action returns partial view, i'm struggling in incrementing the page variable it always send 1 to the action !!

**Controller**

```
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
        home.Articles = GetArticlesByPage(home.Page);
        return View(home);
        }

    public PartialViewResult NextPageArticles(int page)
        {
        home.Articles = GetArticlesByPage(page);
        return PartialView("~/Views/Home/ArticlePostPartial.cshtml", home.Articles);
        }
```

**HomeViewModel**

```
    public class HomeViewModel
    {
    public IEnumerable<ArticleViewModel> _articles;
    public IEnumerable<ArticleViewModel> Articles
    {
        get { return this._articles; }
        set
        {
            this._articles = value;
            Page++;
        }
    }
    public int Page { get; set; }

    public HomeViewModel()
    {
        Page = 0;
    }
}
```

**View**

```
<div id="MainContainer" class="container-fluid">
      @{Html.RenderPartial("ArticlePostPartial", Model.Articles);}
</div>
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("NextPageArticles", "Home", new { page = ??? }, new AjaxOptions
    {
        InsertionMode = InsertionMode.InsertAfter,
        UpdateTargetId = "MainContainer",
        LoadingElementId = "imgload",
        OnSuccess = "OnSuccessAjax"
    }))
{
    <input type="submit" id="formbut" class="btn btn-danger hidden" />
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work for you.

```
<div id="MainContainer" class="container-fluid">
      @{Html.RenderPartial("ArticlePostPartial", Model.Articles);}
</div>
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("NextPageArticles", "Home", new { page = Convert.ToInt32(Request.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["page"]) + 1 }, new AjaxOptions
    {
        InsertionMode = InsertionMode.InsertAfter,
        UpdateTargetId = "MainContainer",
        LoadingElementId = "imgload",
        OnSuccess = "OnSuccessAjax"
    }))
{
    <input type="submit" id="formbut" class="btn btn-danger hidden" />
}
```